# No image displayed while access application (Apache Tomcat)

Tags: apache, tomcat

I installed a application which requires Weblogic, Apache/Tomcat. I installed Weblogic, Apache/Tomcat and application and it seems that those are clean installation.

I am able to up Weblogic and Apache/Tomcat cleanly because I didn't see any error/warning in Weblogic log and Apache/Tomcat log.

The problem is when I am accessing application, I am not getting any image/theme. It seems all images/themes are correctly placed and referenced within application.

I am suspecting the problem somewhere in Apache because I am getting login page that's servlet but there is no image.

As per my knowledge (may be incorrect), Apache handles static part of application and Tomcat handles Java part and because I am getting login page, I believe Tomcat is working fine but Apache is not.

I have very little knowledge about Apache port and mod-jk etc. configuration. Please help.

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: Can you please suggest what configuration do I need to post?

Comment: Recently I noticed one thing. I access application by using url http://127.0.0.1:8009 (on tomcat port) and it seems that I am only getting response from servlet. I can see image place holder but no image in it. When I right click, copy link of image (like http://127.0.0.1:8009/XXX) and paste it in browser, no image display but when I change the port to 80 (like http://127.0.0.1:80/XXX) then I can see image but I can not access application on port 80. Is it possible that apache and tomcat are not cordinating with each other?